# io.connect adding "3000" to url

Tags: express, socket.io

In my javascript I'm doing:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://socket.xxxxxxxxxxx.net?token=socket1');
```

And the url in the "network" tab  of chrome reads as

"https://socket.xxxxxxxxx.net:3000/socket.io/1/?token=socket1&t=1394492903833"

And I get an ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I think this is because it's appending port 300 to my url, when, on the server, there is nothing running on port 3000.

My environment is a node.js server running on my local machine, and serving files through express, if this matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is to explicitly add the correct port, in my case 443, to the connection url.

Like so

```
https://socket.xxxxxxxxx.net:443/socket.io/1/?token=socket1&t=1394492903833
```